# How to run a python script from a HTML page without the use of a server? It should serve the purpose of a GUI Frame

Tags: python, html

I developed an ML model which requires two arguments, which are the path of the two files used by the model function. The task at hand requires a web page which could take those arguments for the model and deliver it to the function.

The job could also be done using Tkinter in python for developing a GUI Frame, but my situation requires a web page for further development.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that

Answer (score 1):

You could use flask, pyramid, or django to make a web-app that will call your ML function.It doesent have to be hosted on a server you can run it locally on your computer.

What isn't clear is why in your particular case you can't use Tkinter. Is your webpage suppose to be accesed by someone else ? From outside you local network ? 
The question isn't verry clear.

Comment: No it has to be accessed from the same local machine inside the network.

Comment: So it's all on accesed and used on your local machine. Then the answer still stands. Oh and another possibility is to use sockets to send the data, python for your ml and javascript for the html.

Comment: You can then just access the local server from `localhost`. You could also bind your server to localhost so it only listens on your local machine

Comment: for example you have html code includes JavaScript that create svg file or png image how make this app work as terminal app without open browser or setup flask like just excute this html and js and even call API with js to get result, in background like when done in selenuim when work in background so even if on linux or corn job or automated it work alone